# How to PowerShell 2 or 3 when creating RunSpace?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, runspace

On a computer with PowerShell 2.0 and PowerShell 3.0 installed, how can I select which is started from my C# app when I create the RunSpace?

It seems there are all kinds of configuration parameters, but none that control which version of PowerShell is started.  I can imagine it might be based on the version of .NET used for the calling process, but what about when you call RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace?  In that case, it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: *might* be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16148305/21567). IOW, the powershell version is bound to the .NET version. You'd have to specify in your app.config which .NET version you support and thus which PS version you get.

Comment: That makes sense, except when PowerShell is launched out of process.  Then I would think you could attach to either.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the overload of CreateOutOfProcessRunspace that takes a PowerShellProcessInstance, and you need to specify the version when creating the PowerShellProcessInstance.

```
PowerShellProcessInstance instance = new PowerShellProcessInstance(new Version(2, 0), null, null, false);
using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(new TypeTable(new string[0]), instance))
{
    rs.Open();
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.Runspace = rs;
        ps.AddScript("$PSVersionTable");

        dynamic vt = ps.Invoke().Single();

        Console.WriteLine(vt.PSVersion); // This will output "2.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new 3.0 version of System.Management.Automation.dll that PowerShell v3 shipped with.  You could try preemptively loading the 3.0 SMA dll using Assembly.Load() early in your startup code to cause PowerShell v3 to be loaded.