# C# The term 'Get-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program on 64 bit application

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I have an windows form application in which I want run power shell command.

```
Runspace _runspace = null;
Pipeline _pipeline = null;
Runspace _runspaceConfig = null;
_runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
_runspaceConfig = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
_runspaceConfig.Open();
_pipeline = _runspaceConfig.CreatePipeline();
_pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
_pipeline.Invoke();
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "servermanager" });
_runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
_runspace.Open();
Collection<PSObject> response = new Collection<PSObject>();
RunspaceConfiguration rc = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
var runspaceConfig = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rc);
runspaceConfig.Open();
var pipeline = runspaceConfig.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-RD-Server");
response = pipeline.Invoke();
```

I am running application in 64bit on windows server 2012R2
compiling in x64. In VS go to Project > Properties > Build - Platform Target = x64.
application throw error " The term 'Get-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
I need help to solve issue.

Comment: That command is probably part of an unloaded module. I'm not sure, if your self created runspace will automatically load modules not being part of GAC...

Comment: Have you tried running the same code without the `ImportPSModule` instruction? I would expect it's not required (Module auto-loading is present from PS3 and up). I'm not saying it'll work, just wondering if that may somehow change the default behavior of module loading...

Comment: If i add above code into new console application and run on same machine then it is working. The problem is with winform application.

Comment: Verify your code actually creates an instance of PowerShell with the proper version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148305/call-a-specific-version-of-powershell-from-c-sharp for more details.